# Parsing json Array Ajax Return Data

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, jquery

Can somebody explain me how do i parse this Ajax response in jQuery

```
{"d":{"__type":"ListUsers+returnData","Type":"Success","Message":"User Added successfully."}}
```

I am using same return types for different return data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = '{"d":{"__type":"ListUsers+returnData","Type":"Success","Message":"User Added successfully."}}'
data = JSON.parse(data);
alert(data.d.Type);
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/8uSWP/